# A socket exception occurred in the current NetMQMonitorSocketEventArgs

Tags: c#, sockets

As I am using netmq in my current project, the current NetMQMonitorSocketEventArgs throws a socketException. Can you tell me the reason in detail?

This  situation occurs when the server is under load.

I'm testing on my local pc, can the monitor restart itself? ?????

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: In addition, please always provide enough information to reproduce the problem and all information about the error that is available for you (in this case at least the details of the `SocketException`). We can not just _guess_ what the problem is...